# Aligning these three containers evenly

Tags: css, html, css-float

I would like this layout to look as follows:

```
__________________________
|  |                      |
|  ------------------------
|__|______________________|
```

That is how I want the header to look. However, as you can see at the below link, the two div's on the right side are dropping off:
http://jsfiddle.net/A5YDJ/3/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add `float:left` to the #left-box

```
#left-box{
 width:190px;
 height:90px;
 background-color:blue; 
 float:left;
}
```

Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/puCrJ/

Comment: I will accept this answer in 8 minutes - I can't believe it was something that simple...

Comment: Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct CSS, you were floating the wrong div's:

```
#left-box{
    width:190px;
    height:90px;
    background-color:blue; 
    float:left;
}

#top-rel-container{
    float:left;
    width:400px;
    height:90px;
}
#head-top-thin{
    height:45px;
    background-color:red;
    width:400px;
}
#head-bottom-thin{
    width:400px;
    height:45px;
    background-color:green;
}

#cont{
    width:100%;
    height:90px;
    margin:0 auto;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
float:left;
```

Check you updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/A5YDJ/4/)